# Unity game fails to start

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have created a very simple rock paper scissors game based solely on Unity's GUI.It runs perfectly in play mode and does not even show me a warning.

If I try to start it, however, no matter what settings I choose, it shows the unity logo, then a white screen and then it closes.It does not even crashes.Once or twice it crashed with access violation, but since I've added materials to all the things that can have materials it never does that, it simply closes.I've tried the windows compatibility thing and at some point it said that the program was "incompatible",altough it is built for x86_64 windows using unity 5.

Here is the output_log.txt

> Mono path[0] = 'D:/Unity Projects/RPS/Builds/2.0_Data/Managed' Mono
>   path[1] = 'D:/Unity Projects/RPS/Builds/2.0_Data/Mono' Mono config
>   path = 'D:/Unity Projects/RPS/Builds/2.0_Data/Mono/etc'
>   PlayerConnection initialized from D:/Unity
>   Projects/RPS/Builds/2.0_Data (debug = 0) PlayerConnection initialized
>   network socket : 0.0.0.0 55080 Multi-casting "[IP] 192.168.0.107
>   [Port] 55080 [Flags] 3 [Guid] 3182763067 [EditorId] 2204854871
>   [Version] 1048832 [Id] WindowsPlayer(costica-pc) [Debug] 1" to
>   [225.0.0.222:54997]... Waiting for connection from host on
>   [192.168.0.107:55080]... PlayerConnection accepted from
>   [192.168.0.107] handle:0x2fc Using monoOptions
>   --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,embedding=1,defer=y,address=0.0.0.0:56067
>   PlayerConnection already initialized - listening to
>   [192.168.0.107:55080] Initialize engine version: 5.4.1f1
>   (649f48bbbf0f) GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=1 Direct3D:
>       Version:  Direct3D 11.0 [level 11.0]
>       Renderer: NVIDIA GeForce GT 630 (ID=0xf00)
>       Vendor:   NVIDIA
>       VRAM:     972 MB Begin MonoManager ReloadAssembly Platform assembly: D:\Unity
>   Projects\RPS\Builds\2.0_Data\Managed\UnityEngine.dll (this message is
>   harmless) Loading D:\Unity
>   Projects\RPS\Builds\2.0_Data\Managed\UnityEngine.dll into Unity Child
>   Domain Platform assembly: D:\Unity
>   Projects\RPS\Builds\2.0_Data\Managed\Assembly-CSharp.dll (this message
>   is harmless) Loading D:\Unity
>   Projects\RPS\Builds\2.0_Data\Managed\Assembly-CSharp.dll into Unity
>   Child Domain Platform assembly: D:\Unity
>   Projects\RPS\Builds\2.0_Data\Managed\Assembly-UnityScript.dll (this
>   message is harmless) Loading D:\Unity
>   Projects\RPS\Builds\2.0_Data\Managed\Assembly-UnityScript.dll into
>   Unity Child Domain Platform assembly: D:\Unity
>   Projects\RPS\Builds\2.0_Data\Managed\UnityEngine.UI.dll (this message
>   is harmless) Loading D:\Unity
>   Projects\RPS\Builds\2.0_Data\Managed\UnityEngine.UI.dll into Unity
>   Child Domain Platform assembly: D:\Unity
>   Projects\RPS\Builds\2.0_Data\Managed\UnityEngine.Networking.dll (this
>   message is harmless) Loading D:\Unity
>   Projects\RPS\Builds\2.0_Data\Managed\UnityEngine.Networking.dll into
>   Unity Child Domain Platform assembly: D:\Unity
>   Projects\RPS\Builds\2.0_Data\Managed\UnityEngine.Analytics.dll (this
>   message is harmless) Loading D:\Unity
>   Projects\RPS\Builds\2.0_Data\Managed\UnityEngine.Analytics.dll into
>   Unity Child Domain
>   - Completed reload, in  0.220 seconds Platform assembly: D:\Unity Projects\RPS\Builds\2.0_Data\Managed\System.Core.dll (this message is
>   harmless) Platform assembly: D:\Unity
>   Projects\RPS\Builds\2.0_Data\Managed\System.dll (this message is
>   harmless) desktop: 1920x1080 60Hz; virtual: 1920x1080 at 0,0 
>   Initializing input.
>
> Input initialized.
>
> Initialized touch support.
>
> UnloadTime: 2.366758 ms Setting up 1 worker threads for Enlighten.
>   Thread -> id: 22b4 -> priority: 1  Waiting for finish

I really do not know what else to do.Any kind of feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is this related to `c#` ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I just realised it has nothing to do with it.I have changed the tags.

Comment: Is this related only to this project? Create an empty project an build it. Same result? Do you have Application.Quit() anywhere in your code?

Comment: Yes, I have Application.Quit() as part of a script that is a component to a button.And yes, I have just built an empty project and it builds.I honestly have no idea what to do anymore, and I can't even create the project again from scratch because I do not know where the error lies.

Comment: try changing player settings -> other settings -> rendering

Answer (score -1):

I have realised the problem.Someone made a comment asking me if I had `Application.Quit()` anywhere in my code, and I did, as a component to a button.However, the script would be activated on `Awake` instead of when the button was pressed.

Comment: you can add application.quit() anywhere you want when you press your button, awake is not a solution(this answer is not a solution)